# can git not commit a file if the file contains certain words?

Tags: git

Maybe this question is repeated but I couldn't find anything.

Let's suppose I'm developing with ruby and I'm debugging a file with byebug, so in that file I have the word "byebug".

I find the problem and save that correct file but I forget to remove the byebug word. so when I commit that file, it will be commited with that word, than can cause in production the app not working well.

I'm using magit and emacs, so before committing I always can read the diff and look for the "byebug" word. If there it is I can remove.

I also know that I can do something similar to `git diff | grep byebug` and detect if there is the bybug word, But I want to know if this can be possible only with using git, or the correct way to this automatically with git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Git hooks. Hooks are scripts that are run at different stages (pre-commit, post-commit) and can prevent the action to succeed.

I think that in your case the client-side pre-commit hook is what you are looking for. An useful introduction to git hooks https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks